# How to size the width of input field to its max length in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to create a form with an address and apt # field and have the apt # field be sized to its max length of 8 while having the other field take up whatever width is left for this row. I was wondering how I can do this without manually setting the width.

I have something like this:

```html
<style>
.container {
  display: flex;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
  <input placeholder="Address"/>
  <input name="apt" placeholder="Apt #" maxlength=8 />
</div>
```

thanks!

Comment: maxlength of 8 what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flex-grow`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow

You can't actually make the apartment input its `maxlength` as this is referring to the maximum length of characters that input can contain not actually the length of the element itself. But I have made an estimate of the number of characters / 2 in rems to be a good width for the element.

```html
<style>
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.address{
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.apt{
  width: 4rem;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
  <input class="address" placeholder="Address"/>
  <input class="apt" name="apt" placeholder="Apt #" maxlength=8 />
</div>
```